# Full vaccination for France in Canada

Tags: international-travel, france, covid-19, vaccinations

I currently live in Canada and would like to travel to France in about a month from now.

As of today, Canada is in the "green" list of countries with regard to covid, which makes it possible to enter France without a complete vaccination scheme. However, considering increasing cases of infections in Canada, it is possible that Canada moves to the "orange" (i.e. dangerous) list before my trip starts, in which case [full vaccination would be required](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/covid-19/deplacements-internationaux) (I am not traveling for an "important" reason, which would allow entry without vaccination).

I got two shots of Sputnik (August and September 2021) and two shots of Pfizer (October 2021 and July 2022). It seems that this combination is insufficient to be considered as fully vaccinated for France because Sputnik is not recognized and for Pfizer the delay between 1st and 2nd doses should be [between 3 and 7 weeks](https://mesconseilscovid.sante.gouv.fr/je-veux-me-faire-vacciner.html#quel-est-le-delai-a-respecter-entre-la-1-re-et-la-2-e-dose-lors-de-la-vaccination-initiale-primo-vaccination) (in my case it is 8 months). Canadian vaccination clinics refuse to give another shot before 3 months time has lapsed since my most recent vaccination.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is anything I can do within one month to be able to enter France in case Canada becomes "orange"? Any help is appreciated.

PS. I am neither Canadian not French citizen.

Comment: Why do you believe you do not qualify as fully vaccinated? I'll have to check the original rules but AFAIK France only requires a complete series and the last dose to be within 9 months for entry purposes.

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/172847/wording-of-france-fully-vaccinated-entry-requirements?r=SearchResults&s=10%7C30.2333

Comment: @xngtng From what I understood, France does not recognize Sputnik at all, so I only have two shots of Pfizer. For these shots to be accepted as "primo vaccination", there must be 45 days max in-between them, which is not the case unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think there is a 45 day rule but I am not sure. Do you have a source where you read that ? Many people in Canada couldn't got second dose with in 45 days even if they wanted to.

Comment: Not exactly 45 days, but 7 weeks max here: https://mesconseilscovid.sante.gouv.fr/je-veux-me-faire-vacciner.html#quel-est-le-delai-a-respecter-entre-la-1-re-et-la-2-e-dose-lors-de-la-vaccination-initiale-primo-vaccination

Answer (score 2):

The rules for being recognized as *fully vaccinated* in France **from a domestic standpoint** are as follow :

> Si j’ai reçu deux doses de vaccin, je dois faire mon rappel au plus tard quatre mois après ma deuxième injection. [...]

> If I have received two doses of vaccine, I need to do my booster at most 4 month after 2nd injection

(translations and emphasis mine, [source](https://www.gouvernement.fr/actualite/le-pass-vaccinal-mode-d-emploi))

---

#### Entry

From Orange countries (Australia taken here), the rules are TIMATIC says (documentation database) :

> > - a COVID-19 vaccination certificate showing that:
>
> [...]
>
> - they were fully vaccinated with AstraZeneca (SK Bioscience), AstraZeneca (Vaxzevria), Covishield, Fiocruz, Moderna (Spikevax),
>   Nuvaxovid (Novavax), Pfizer-BioNTech (Comirnaty) or R-Covi at least 7
>   days and at most 270 days before arrival; or
> - they were fully vaccinated with AstraZeneca (SK Bioscience), AstraZeneca (Vaxzevria), Covishield, Fiocruz, Moderna (Spikevax),
>   Nuvaxovid (Novavax), Pfizer-BioNTech (Comirnaty) or R-Covi and
>   received a booster dose of Moderna (Spikevax) or Pfizer-BioNTech
>   (Comirnaty) at most 4 months after the last mandatory dose or at least
>   7 days before arrival; or
> - they were fully vaccinated with Covaxin, Sinopharm or Sinovac and received a dose of Moderna (Spikevax) or Pfizer-BioNTech (Comirnaty)
>   at least 7 days before arrival; or

And the [French foreign ministry](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/covid-19-international-travel) says

> proof of vaccination status; Since February 1, 2022, in order for their vaccination schedule to remain recognized as complete, persons aged eighteen or over wishing to enter the national territory must have received a dose of complementary messenger RNA vaccine no later than 9 months following the injection of the last required dose.

Because your last dose hasn't been injected more than 270 days ago, will not be in 1 month since your last shot.

You are counted as fully vaccinated and can enter France, even in the case Canada switches classification. The 4 month time is for domestic use inside the country (in case the *passe vaccinal* is reinstated)

Comment: I am afraid that since France does not recognize Sputnik, I only have two shots of Pfizer, one given 8 months after the other. AFAIK, the maximum period should be below 2 months to be considered fully vaccinated...

Comment: @mintay There are no such regulations in France, from the French official stance, you **are** fully vaccinated as you have 2 dose of EMA vaccine at least until 4 months (for the *passe vaccinal*) and 9 months (for entry) after that last dose

Comment: I remember seeing this on some French website... I will try to find the source.

Comment: This is not exactly how I remember it, but this website says that delay must be between 3 and 7 weeks: https://mesconseilscovid.sante.gouv.fr/je-veux-me-faire-vacciner.html#quel-est-le-delai-a-respecter-entre-la-1-re-et-la-2-e-dose-lors-de-la-vaccination-initiale-primo-vaccination

Comment: @mintay Medical advice/recommendation is different from legal requirement.

Comment: @xngtng, I agree that medical advice is not the same as legal requirement, but this website seems government-ish and does not phrase 7 weeks delay as advice except for the "conseils" word in the address. I.e. I cannot conclude from the available information that 7 weeks delay is great but 32 weeks is fine too. I'd be happy to, but it seems like a grey area for the moment...

Comment: I would bet that this only applies, seeing what site it is, to vaccination made in France, and doesn't apply to shots aborad, I am pretty sure you're in the clear, all sources go the same way

Comment: @mintay even medical laws or conditions of approval of a medication have no relevance to entry requirements which only require two doses without specifying waiting period.